# Error in JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using brackets to learn web page development. Suddenly jQuery stopped working. JavaScript is showing the following errors.

- ESLint

  ERRORS: '$' is not defined. [no-undef]
   ERRORS: 'window' is not defined.[no-undef]

After restarting pc some sort of alert popped up while opening brackets, saying some firewall issues are booking some features. And don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

You must define the globals variables in `.eslintrc`

this is my .eslintrc

```
module.exports = {
 "env": {
    "node": true, // this is the best starting point
    "browser": true, // for react web
    "es6": true // enables es6 features
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint", // needed to make babel stuff work properly
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "globals": {
    "$": true,
    "window": true,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Solution

You should declare jQuery and window in your [ESLint config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) file. Create a file called `.eslintrc.json` and type the following json

```
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "commonjs": true,
  "es6": true,
  "jquery": true
}
```

### Why

ESLint and almost all javascript linters works not only in browser context but also in node.js. For this reason you have to specify your environment. The reason behind this is that ESLint should highlight particular details exposed in each environment, for instance, the global variable `window` in javascript in the browser context doesn't exist on node.js since the global variable on node is called `global`. The flag `commonjs` tells to ESLint that you want to use the common scope and global variables of Browser Javascript in the browser context. You shouldn't use `"commonjs": true` if you have `"browser": false`, because you want to use `commonjs` if you are in the browser context. The flag `es6` tells the linter that you want to use one of the latest features of Javascript. If you are not aware of [es6](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/write-less-do-more-with-javascript-es6-5fd4a8e50ee2) I'd highly encourage you to learn about it. In any case, you can remove `es6` if you want to, it's totally optional. Finally `"jquery": true` would accept jQuery global variables.

Comment: I'm working with my own copy of jQuery.
Can you tell me a little about ESLint config file?